# Listview items with 25% height

Tags: android, listview, height, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview and im populating it with a custom adapter. I want all my listview items to have a height of 25%. I tried to use layout weights with no result. Any help?

here is my code

**NavigationAdapter**

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] NavigationTexts;
    private final String[] NavigationImages;

    public NavigationAdapter(Activity context, String[] NavigationTexts, String[] NavigationImages) {
        super(context, R.layout.navigation_layout, NavigationTexts);

        this.context=context;
        this.NavigationTexts=NavigationTexts;
        this.NavigationImages=NavigationImages;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_layout, parent, false);

        TextView Name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.NavigationText);
        ImageView ImgButton = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.NavigationImage);


        Name.setText(NavigationTexts[position]);
        int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(NavigationImages[position], "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
        ImgButton.setImageResource(resID);

        return rowView;

    }

}
```

**and my layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/NavigationImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/NavigationText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NavigationImage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes ,good. Tell me, you want to have 4 listview items each taking 25% of the space? Or you want something else to take 25% space?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it manually in your customAdapter. As you already override onCreateViewHolder method and inflating actual layout for list item, you can this:

pseudo code:

```
var listViewHeight = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().height / 4;
//if you have toolbar or some other component, take its height into calculation also.
View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
View listViewContainer = view.findViewById(containerId);
listViewContainer.getLayoutParams().height = listViewheight;
```

UPDATE:

I would suggest to use RecyclerView instead of ListView and RecyclerView.Adapter instead of ArrayAdapter. But to answer your question:

Its same logic as above.

Set id to parent RelativeLayout to "layoutContainer" or something, and use lines from above in your getView() method.